# How to make a Windows Form responsive

Tags: c#, winforms, responsive-design

I am creating a Windows Form for a project, but I'm not able to make it responsive.
I have following picture:

[image: This is the default Window]

When I extend the Window, it should be responsive, but I get this:

[image: Extended Window]

I added layouts in the window, but I don't know how to manage them correctly. Could you give me a few tips ?

Comment: What is your definition of "responsive"?

Comment: When I extend the window, the picture on the right goes on the right of the window and the Title is centered in the window

Comment: You mean the basics as `anchor` and so on? Do you want to enable `scroll` if the form size gets small? And basically what @PatrickHofman says

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/c5c6e2/dynamically-resizing-controls-on-windows-forms-using-ancho/

Comment: @PatrickHofman thanks for the link ! I managed to solve my problem ;)